# How to improve search engine comprehension of the page?

Tags: search-engine

Besides using schema, what else can I do to improve the search engine comprehension of the page such that when, let's say an article's title is searched, the search engine can show my website as one of the top results because it matches an article in my page.

Or let's say my website is one of the very few websites about how to make avocado chicken pudding, so when the phrase "avocado chicken pudding" is searched, my website would show up at top results.

And what affects the ranking of the page? Is it traffic? or something else (like public review?!)

Answer (score 0):

Questions like these belong to the field of [SEO (Search Engine Optimization)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization).

Have a look at questions tagged [seo](/questions/tagged/seo) (many on [on Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seo), too). *But: beware of the [snake oil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil)!*

In general:

- it depends on the search engine, they all differ
- some search engines won't tell you (exactly) *how* they rank

Most search engines rely on two primary factors for ranking pages:

- content/keywords (→ what is the page about?)
- backlinks (→ is the page important/useful/…?)

The content is in your control, the backlinks (typically) not.

Always keep in mind: if you *could* manipulate your ranking for a certain keyword, your competitors could do it, too. *What now?*

The simplest and best SEO advice is also the hardest to put into practice: Write good, useful content.